# Ajax get request to wsdl web-service

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services, wsdl

i have wsdl file and i need get data from. How i can do this ? i'm trying do this with ajax 
like this:

```
jq.ajax({
   url: 'http://url.wsdl',
   type: 'get',
   success: function(data){
     alert("OK  " + data); 
   },
   error: function (x, y, z) {
     alert("ERROR");
   }
});
```

what i do wrong ?

Any other way to get data from wsdl web service using javascript, jquery and etc. is?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are missing is a data: {}
I read that there was some sort of bug if you did not include that when using $.ajax
Oh, and most likely you are going to need dataType: "json" or whatever datatype the service is using.

Here is an example i am using against an online webservice:

```
jQuery.support.cors = true; //enables cross domain queries for Ajax
$('#jqueryBtn').click
    (function () 
    {
        $.ajax
            (
                {

                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://www.webservicemart.com//uszip.asmx/ValidateZip",
                    data: { 'ZipCode': '22553' },
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: jqSuccess,
                    error: jqError
                }
            );
    }
```

Hopefully you can use this example to fix your own code

Answer (score 0):

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ajax-to-call-a-wsdl-web-service

The following link should explain why you cannot use AJAX for cross domain queries:
http://www.w3schools.com/xmL/xml_parser.asp:

> Access Across Domains
>
> For security reasons, modern browsers do not allow access across
>   domains.
>
> This means, that both the web page and the file it tries to load,
>   must be located on the same server.
>
> The examples on W3Schools all open XML files located on the W3Schools
>   domain.
>
> If you want to use the example above on one of your web pages, the file you load must be located on your own server.

You can create a proxy web page in your web server to access to WSDL web service and return result to the AJAX request